# How do i post phone number and message to Twilio controller using forms?

Tags: twilio

Sending a message from Twilio is succesful, now i want to be able to enter the TO phone number the message body from a form, but i'm not sure which method is the best. I'm thinking maybe calling a variable from another ViewController but i am not sure if that would work, suggestions?

Here is my twilio controller

```
 public IActionResult Sendsms()
            {


                var accountSid = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
                var authToken = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
                TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

                var to = new PhoneNumber("+XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
                var from = new PhoneNumber("+XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

                var message = MessageResource.Create(to: to,
                    from: from,
                    body: "this is the ship that made the kessel run in 14 parsecs?");

                return Content(message.Sid);

            }
```